# Why do I get wrong, doubled input value on keyup when typing fast?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, dom-events, return-value

```
$("#input").keyup(function(){
 console.log($(this).val());
})
```

When one is typing slowly "a" & "b" the above code will result in "a", "b" in the console log. But the problem is when somebody does it quickly. The result then is "ab", "ab". It's easier to repeat this situation with letters which are near on a keyboard e.g. "e" & "r". **How to avoid it?**

Events keydown and keypress does not suffer from this problem of quick-typist, but they are also fire to early. Result: returned value of an input does not contain the last typed letter when they occur. Or maybe there is a way to get this last letter somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the problem is not really fast typing, but actually when the key up event happens. Consider this:

- a is pressed
- b is pressed
- a is released
- b is released

No matter how slowly this is done, you will not get the key up event until the first key is released. There is obviously no way around this, you can't cause the key up event before the key is released.

If you just want the key that is pressed in a key press event, you can get it from the event object. Example:

```
$('#input').keypress(function(e){
  console.log(e.which);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found a workaround. Basically, I created an array with the timeStamp of the event (e.timeStamp) for every time the keyup fired. Then I compared the last two values in the array (the two most recent) and stopped the event if the difference in time wasn't at least 100ms.

This is my code inside the function called by the keyup listener:

```
timeArray.push(e.timeStamp); // add new timeStamp to array      
if (timeArray.length >= 2) { 
        var diff = (timeArray[timeArray.length - 1] - timeArray[timeArray.length - 2]);
        if (diff > 100) {   // 1 second
                // perform desired action
        } else { return false; }
} else {
            // still perform desired action if array only has one timestamp
        }
```